# NextJS error importing component with local image from other package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a monorepo that has a NextJS project and a React library. I want to import components from the react project to the nextjs project. So far so good... but when I try to import a component that has a local image in it I get the following error:

*Automatic publicPath is not supported in this browser*

I understand that I have to put the path of the assets in the webpack config file, but even doing that NextJS can't resolve the images. What am i missing?

I've replicated the error in an public repository so you could see what's happening.

**Component library:**

```
import React from "react";

const TestComponent = () => (
  <div>
    <p>Test Component</p>
    <img src={require("./arrow-down.png").default} width="10px" height="10px" />
  </div>
);

export default TestComponent;
```

**NextJS importing the component:**

```
import TestComponent from "react-project";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <TestComponent />
    </div>
  );
}
```

The project has the following structure
-- packages
-- nextjs-project
-- react-project
-- package.json

[public repository.](https://github.com/lucaford/nextjs-images-error)

You only need to install the dependencies with yarn (or npm if you like) and build the react library with webpack (yarn build).

I know im missing some theory about images in NextJS.
Thank you!

Comment: if your component library will only be used in nextjs applications, use the `<Image />` component https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image

Comment: @Samathingamajig but I am using a React library and the TestComponent, with the local image, is in React. Do you say that I should use <Image /> anyways? I don't see it as a solution but maybe I am missing something

Answer (score 0):

first you'll need to install this package to devDependencies:

```
npm i -D file-loader
yarn add -D file-loader
```

then you'll need to add the following to "rules" inside the webpack.config :

```
{
  test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
  use: [
        {
          loader: 'file-loader',
        },
      ],
},
```

- And finally, you'll need to switch the require with an import. maybe it can be pulled of with a require method but i'm not familiar enough with it.

Comment: Hi! first thanks for your answer.

Im already using file-loader in the react project and that didn't do the job.
Here you have my webpack config: https://github.com/lucaford/nextjs-images-error/blob/main/packages/react-project/webpack.config.js